# ssl for an absolute beginner

Tags: php, security, cakephp, ssl

i have developing a website with cakephp and now i want to implement ssl in it, but i have zero knowledge about ssl.

is an ssl certificate and some changes in the httpd.conf is all that's required for secure connection and does that mean that my sessions and form data are secure? or should i add additional code?

i've searched some websites on ssl and implemented it on my localhost by creating a self signed certificate,made some changes in the httpd.conf file,added an exception in my browser and everthing works fine.

is that it or is it just the beginning?

php also provides with some openssl functions. do i need to implement it?

Comment: Google would help you more for such kind of request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to use any of PHP's SSL functions, or change your code at all. *Unless* you have URLs in your code that include 'http://', which will either fail (if you make SSL required) or be insecure (if you leave non-SSL HTTP available). The HTTP server provides a secure channel to the client, so your HTTP traffic - all your page contents, form data and so on - is all protected automatically.

Comment: thanks. how can i choose a specific encryption tecnique

Comment: @LalithMohan http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html  Explains all the SSL options which allow you to specify encryption modes that will be negotiated with the client.